# Trigger en Postgres de inserción con datos seleccionados con una condición where que se obtiene después de insertar

Tags: postgresql

El código de la condición `where` se debe obtener después de crear, es decir, al crear un registro en la tabla *expediente* tiene que disparar el trigger que tome como dato el id del registro creado en la tabla *expediente* y pasarle como parámetro en la condición `WHERE`.

```
 INSERT INTO public.anexos
 (idtipodoc, idexp, estadoanexo, created_at, updated_at)
 select td.idtipodocumento, e.idexpediente, e.estadoexpediente, e.created_at, e.updated_at from detalleplantilla d inner join plantilla p on d.idplantilla = p.idplantilla 
 inner join tramite t on p.idplantilla = t.idplantilla 
 inner join expediente e on e.idtramite = t.idtramite
 inner join tipo_documento td on d.idtipodocumento = td.idtipodocumento 
 **where e.idexpediente = 33**
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando una función retorna un trigger, puedes invocarla desde un idem [contando con algunas convenciones](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) tal que ciertos parámetros son implícitos. En particular, la convención que te sirve es que `NEW` alude al nuevo registro (ya sea insertado o actualizado)

En la siguiente función

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_to_anexos()   
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.anexos  (idtipodoc, idexp, estadoanexo, created_at, updated_at)
    select td.idtipodocumento, e.idexpediente, e.estadoexpediente, e.created_at, e.updated_at from detalleplantilla d inner join plantilla p on d.idplantilla = p.idplantilla 
    inner join tramite t on p.idplantilla = t.idplantilla 
    inner join expediente e on e.idtramite = t.idtramite
    inner join tipo_documento td on d.idtipodocumento = td.idtipodocumento
    WHERE e.idexpediente = NEW.id
    RETURN NEW; 
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

`NEW.id` es el ID del expediente recién creado. Y para invocarla en cada inserción, declaras el trigger propiamente tal:

```
CREATE TRIGGER expediente_created
AFTER INSERT ON expediente 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE  insert_to_anexos();
```

Posiblemente tendrás que tunear un poco la implementación usando aislamiento de transacciones (el trigger obedece al aislamiento del insert en este caso) o declararlo diferido (pero esto requiere que sea un CONSTRAINT TRIGGER y nunca lo he probado).